# java.net.BindException Client-side after thousands of quick-fire Socket connections to Server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

My Platform is Windows 10 Enterprise with JDK 17.

Anyone know why the following Client crashes with a java.net.BindException after many thousand connections?

(it seems to be timing-related because, with a 10ms sleep between executions, it just runs and runs and runs...)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        final byte[] readBuffer = new byte[8192];

        while (true) {
            try (   final Socket                socket  = new Socket("localhost", 1972);
                    final InputStream           ist     = socket.getInputStream();
                    final OutputStream          ost     = socket.getOutputStream();
                    final ByteArrayOutputStream istBAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
            {
                ost.write("Hello!".getBytes());
                socket.shutdownOutput();

                int    readCount;
                while((readCount = ist.read(readBuffer)) != -1) {
                    istBAOS.write(readBuffer, 0, readCount);
                }
                final byte[] istBytes = istBAOS.toByteArray();

                socket.shutdownInput();

                System.out.println("Client.: " + socket + " <- " + new String(istBytes));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Server, which seems to be fine:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        final byte[] readBuffer = new byte[8192];

        try (           final ServerSocket          server  = new ServerSocket(1972)) {
            while (true) {
                try (   final Socket                socket  = server.accept();
                        final InputStream           ist     = socket.getInputStream();
                        final OutputStream          ost     = socket.getOutputStream();
                        final ByteArrayOutputStream istBAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
                {
                    int    readCount;
                    while((readCount = ist.read(readBuffer)) != -1) {
                        istBAOS.write(readBuffer, 0, readCount);
                    }
                    final byte[] istBytes = istBAOS.toByteArray();

                    socket.shutdownInput();
                    ost.write(istBytes);
                    socket.shutdownOutput();
                }
                catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
//              try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch (final InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my initial assumption, it is a timing issue, was correct.

The following article deals with the so-called `TIME-WAIT` State:
[Coping with the TCP TIME-WAIT state on busy Linux servers](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux)

One takeaway is:
*"Moreover, when designing protocols, don’t let clients close first. Clients won’t have to deal with the TIME-WAIT state pushing the responsibility to servers which are better suited to handle this."*

For my load test, I just need to make sure that I don't cycle through all available Ports in less than the 2 Minute latency specified in the Standard. Right now my System has 16,263 Ports available, which means under constant fire, I need to limit it to minimum 7.4 ms between Connections.